# Providing a common framework to access map/list/vector in c++

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am trying to provide a common framework to write a map or vector(if possible list as well) to a file.
My implementation consists of an abstract class `class CStorage` which would be used to provide interfaces to read and write into the file.

For eg. I have two different databases to be written to two different files - one uses a `map` as a private member in class to store the data, and the other database uses `list` as a private member in class to store the data.

Now is there a way to provide a general implementation(in `class CGeneralContainer`) to access both a `list` and a `map` in a class that derives from the abstract class mentioned above(`CStorage`)?

I understand the templates could be used for generalized implementation.

Can templates be used for such a use case?

Below is the pseudo code for the same:

```
class CPlace
{
    /*
    * class describing the name, lat and long of a place.
    */
    CPlace();
    ~CPlace();

    private:
        string m_name;
        double m_latitude;
        double m_longitude;
}


class CPlaceDB
{
  /*
  * Database class, which holds the map of different place.
  */
  CPlaceDB();
  ~CPlaceDB();

  typedef std::map<string,CPlace> PlaceMap;

  private:
    PlaceMap m_placeMap;

}


class CStorage
{
    /*
    * abstract class providing interface to read and write to a file.
    */
    CStorage();
    ~CStorage();

    virtual bool writeData(const CPlaceDB& w_PlaceDB) = 0; //write the database to a file
    virtual bool readData(CPlaceDB& r_PlaceDB) = 0; //read database from file.
}


class CGeneralContainer : public CStorage
{
  /* class which would provide a general implementation
  * to read and write a map or a list or a vector
  */

}
```

In case  if there is a change to `typedef std::map<string,CPlace> PlaceMap;` to a new type  `typedef std::list<CPlace> PlaceList`, then I would like to use the same `class CGeneralContainer` to be able to use the same methods as implemented previously to read and write to a file.

Comment: It's unlikely you would be able to generalize maps and vectors - maps have keys, while vectors do not. As for any sequence containers, standard STL algos already provide good level of generalization.

Comment: It's obviously possible, but there will be many ways to do it. Can you give a more concrete example, with code to give some idea of your intent?

Comment: @SergeyA you could argue that an index is a key to a vector

Comment: Can you just implement operator<< and use it in your class(es)?

Comment: @RichardHodges, as long as they are numeric... )

Comment: If you provide more detail around what data you're storing in the map/list I am sure the community is waiting for the chance to show off their template programming skills.

Comment: You can also see the map as a container of <key, value> pairs, with the oddity that no two entries share a key portion of the pair. That's how it looks from the point of view of the iterators it supplies to fulfill the [`Container`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) concept, even.

Comment: @RichardHodges : pseudo code added for more details.

Comment: Is it your intent that data written from the PlaceMap could be read by the PlaceList?

Comment: @RichardHodges . No. my intent is if I have another class eg `class Route` which consists of a private member `std::list<CPlace>`, then I would want to use the same methods of `class CGeneralContainer` to read and write in a file.

Comment: @user2559758 you may want to take a look at the boost::serialization library. I think this has already been solved for you. You would simply implement a new archive type if the existing text and binary archives are not to your liking.